# How to enable pear and phpunit in xampp on linux?

Tags: php, phpunit, xampp, pear

I have installed xampp 1.8.0 on my ubuntu 12.04 OS. It is installed successfully.
But I want to enable pear and phpunit. I can see there are pear and phpunit directories respectably at /opt/lampp/lib/php/PEAR and /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit
But If I run ***pear -v*** from terminal, it says that

```
The program 'pear' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

Please help me enabling pear and phpunit in xampp.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add `/opt/lampp/lib/bin/` to your `$PATH`.